# AerSimulator measurements

Tags: qiskit, measurement

When I use the simulator

```
Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')
```

and the circuit contains measurements at the end, how do Qiskit performs these measurements?

I thought that it calculates the statevector and use it to obtain the measurements. But if I try to obtain the statevector for a circuit with a large amount of qubits, the RAM can't handle the problem, otherwhise if I add measurements at the end of the circuit (without the state vector), it takes few seconds.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it could be that the RAM collapses in the copying of the large state vector to you, from C++ to Python.

Comment: Can you add your code to the question? Or tell what is the error message if any?